# MessageGroupStoreReaper fails with "was expecting a single payload" IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a simple Spring Integration 2.0.1 aggregator setup, using a SimpleMessageStore along with a regular Spring MessageGroupStoreReaper defined, in order to be able to implement a grouping timeout mechanism (which worked simply as an aggregator 'timeout' parameter in Spring Integration 1.0.4).

I already debugged and verified the messages are aggregated correctly within SimpleMessageStore based on groupId, but upon timeout the MessageGroupStoreReaper fails, with "Unable to access property 'messages' through getter" AccessException. The precise error is located within [MessagingMethodInvokerHelper class](http://git.springsource.org/spring-integration/spring-integration/blobs/ff7c0fe3096d3dc36c890cd7abea6e8060b0c5c8/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/util/MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java), which asserts the messages field is not null. It seems somehow the messages aggregated are not available during execution of the Invoker, resulting in the ""Invalid method parameter for messages: was expecting a single payload." IllegalStateException.

What could be the cause of this issue and how to resolve it?

I already tried updating to 2.0.6, but the issue remains.

***EDIT
I updated my SI dependencies to 2.2.5, but this did not resolve my problem. I use Spring 3.0.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, it seems that the previous setup that worked for SI 1.0.4 required modification on service activator side - the output channel was expecting `List<Message<?>>`, while the actual aggregated type was `Message<List<Message<?>>>`. After modification of activator's method signature to match the latter type, SI was able to match signature candidate properly. This could possibly be also fixed by modification of aggregator add method to operate on specific Message instead of List, with no modifications to the activator.

Comment: Works well also for SI 2.0.1 and Spring 3.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

Only one solution to fix it just to upgrade to latest version of Spring Integration - 2.2.6.
2.0 is now out of support. Sorry

Comment: If the problem I described is a known 2.0.x issue, could you please provide a link with Spring Jira describing it?

Comment: I updated my SI dependencies to 2.2.5 - latest available on Maven repository. The issue is still there. Any ideas?

Comment: Show StackTrace, please

Comment: And configuration too. Thanks

Comment: I see 2.2.6 in Maven Central - http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.integration%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-integration-core%22

Comment: I used http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core